# My shell segfault when I do "kill -11 0"

Tags: c, shell, unix

When I try to do the command "/bin/kill -11 0" on bash, tcsh or zsh, it doesn't segfault but when I try to do it in mine, it does.

So I must have something I didn't handle.

Do you know what it can be ?

Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing any code?

Comment: I have 100 .c files so I dont know what I need to show.

Comment: Where is your debug stacktrace?

Comment: I don't know how I can get a debug stacktrace in C.  Yes my shell catch the signal SIGINT.

Comment: Are you sure those other shells don't segfault when you run that in them?

Comment: @EtanReisner: that depends on how you define "to segfault" :)

Comment: Those shells likely run every non-builtin command (like `/bin/kill`) in a separate process group, not the shell's own process group. Does your shell do this? It's mostly used when the shell wants to support *job control* (Ctrl-Z, `fg`, `bg`, etc.)

Comment: No my shell run the program in his own process group. So to fix this I need to execute the program in another group?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, if you just type kill -11 0 it will segfault because it execute the builtin kill, but if you do /bin/kill -11 0 it wont segfault. In face we don't care if it segfault or not, just shell should not be affected by any signal that are said to the pid 0.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov Would you think the tek1 forum would like to see this question and the answers? Just to put every student equal, you know.

Comment: @Eregrith This test isn't legit anymore so it's ok I don't think a lot of tek1 will be interested now. And my question isn't well formulated so the answers are not either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program doesn't actually segfault when it sends itself signal 11.

If the execution of a programs results in a "segment fault" (that is, the program performs an illegal memory reference), then the operating system sends the program SIGSEGV (signal 11 on Linux). The program cannot distinguish between a SIGSEGV sent by the operating system as the result of a program fault and a SIGSEGV sent by a call to `raise` or `kill`, possibly from another process, so it will respond as though there had been a real program error.

If you want to protect your shell from signals sent to pid 0 from a child process, you need to make sure that your child processes are in a different process group by calling setpgid in the child after the fork.

By default, a program is terminated by SIGSEGV. By default, the shell which invoked the program will then report that the program was terminated by SIGSEGV. This is popularly known as "segfaulting", but as indicated above, it might not have been the result of a real program fault.

If you want your program to do something else, you have to catch signal SIGSEGV with a signal handler; for example, if some cleanup needs to be done before the program terminates. Most shells (and databases) do that, but it is rarely necessary in user code.

**Note:** Signal 11 is `SIGSEGV` on Linux, but there is no guarantee that `SIGSEGV` will be signal 11 on a different OS (or even in some future version of Linux). You should *always* use the name of the signal rather than the number.

Comment: I know all of this, but the fact is, my shell don't have to quit if I send a signal to the pid 0, that's that the real shells do. You can try to do /bin/kill -11 0, your shell that you are using will not quit.  One of my collegue said that I need to use the function setsid, I tried but it didn't worked. That's why I asked here, I hoped someone would know.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov: If you think that your call to `sigaction` is not taking effect, then show the code. If you don't use `sigaction` or `signal` to catch SIGSEGV, then SIGSEGV will terminate your shell.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov: If you send a signal to pid 0, then it gets sent to the process which called kill, and to every other process in the same process group. So it will be sent to your shell. Or maybe I don't understand the precise action you are taking, in which case you could try explaining better or including actual code.

Comment: It's a bad idea to catch SIGSEGV, if my shell segfault I won't know it. And this problem don't need to be solved like this, there is an other way. Even if I catch SIGSEGV, what would happen if I send the signal SIGUSR , i will have to catch this signal too to avoid my shell to quit when I send a signal to the pid 0? It seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: So when I fork, I should create a new group for it?

Comment: @DimitriDanilov: Are you sending the signal to pid 0 from a different process? Yes, you need to create a new process group after you fork.